# Determining a constant with conditions on a limit and an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, improper-integrals

$\pmb{Problem} :$

Given the differential equation :

$(E) : -u''(x) + tanh(x). u(x) = -\lambda.u(x)$

Let $f_n(x) = C_n.cos(\sqrt{\lambda-1}. x). \varphi(\frac{x-n^2}{n})$ where $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $$\varphi(x) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1 & if \ \ x \in [-1, 1]\\ 
0 & if  \ \ \lvert x\rvert \geq 2 \\ 
g(x) &else
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $g \in C^{\infty}$ (That's all we know about the function g)

Let $\alpha_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n^2(x) .dx$

Determine $C_n$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n \neq 0$ $and \int_{-\infty}^\infty L^2(f_n)(x).dx \to 0$   when $n \to +\infty$

where $L(f_n)(x) = -f''_n(x) + tanh(x).f_n(x) - \lambda.f_n(x)$

$\pmb{Discussion :}$

For instance, I started by calculating $f_n ^2(x)$ to evalute $\alpha_n$ in terms of n.
I also tried to solve the differential equation $(E)$ but I couldn't do that due to the hyperbolic tangent (non constant coefficients). In addition, I calculated the first derivative of $f_n$ for the hope of finding a simpler expression of $f_n$ after integrating but all of this didn't get me anything.
So I literally can't find where to begin to address this problem.